# Stackoverflow designer T-shirt suggestions

Tags: discussion, t-shirt

Since like we totally need some Stackoverflow t-shirts and it would be utterly boring for everyone to be wearing the same thing, I thought I would dedicate some April 1st time to design a few new t-shirt for this site. And hopefully when the unicoin exchange crashes tomorrow, you can still buy one using home made bacon ^_^ (p.s. I love pigs!)

Design 1:
[image: t1]

Design 2:
[image: t2]

&& for the elitest of them all ...

[image: t3]